# Convert String to XMPP Stanza using Smack Android

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack, asmack

or

- **Q) Generate XMPP Stanza From String.**
- **Q) Cast String into XMPP Stanza.**

By using Smack library in Android,

```
Message message = new Message();
message.setStanzaId("123");
message.setFrom("923442621149");
message.setType(Message.Type.chat);
message.setBody("shanraisshan");

final String msgString = message.toXML().toString();
Log.e("message --->", msgString);
```

the above code generated following stanza

**msgString:**

```
<message from='923442621149' id='123' type='chat'><body>shanraisshan</body></message>
```

I have save this ***msgString*** into my database.

Now, What I wanted to do is, on retrieving this string back from database

- Cast this ***msgString*** back into Java ***Message*** Class
- so that I can use attributes (***From, Body, Id***)
- using ***message.getFrom()***

---

Since ***Message*** is a child class of ***Stanza***, I tried the below code:

```
Stanza stanza = new Stanza() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence toXML() {
        return msgString;
    }
};
Log.e("stanza XML --->", stanza.toXML().toString());
Log.e("stanza getFrom() ->", stanza.getFrom() + ":");
Log.e("stanza getStanzaId() ->", stanza.getStanzaId() + ":");
```

The Console Log prints follows

```
stanza XML --->: <message from='923442621149' id='123' type='chat'><body>shanraisshan</body></message>
stanza getFrom() ->: null:
stanza getStanzaId() ->: OtU0i-29:
```

I am unable to understand, why

- stanza.toXML().toString() prints the right stanza while
- stanza.getFrom() is ***null*** instead of ***923442621149***
- stanza.getStanzaId() is ***OtU0i-29*** instead of ***123***

---

Plus, on casting Stanza to Message , produces **ClassCastException**

```
Message castedMsg = (Message)stanza;
```

produces

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:
```

---

### **SIMPLIFYING THINGS**

How can I convert **msgString**

```
msgString = "<message from='923442621149' id='123' type='chat'><body>shanraisshan</body></message>";
```

into org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.**Message** class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After going through [Smack Library source code on Github](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack), I found out that the library is using [PacketParserUtils.java](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/5c00172f6a8d6c5f7e39f47badf1ac30fd25bccd/smack-core/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smack/util/PacketParserUtils.java) method's ***parseStanza()*** for casting String to Stanza.

```
String  msgString = "<message from='923442621149' id='123' type='chat'><body>shanraisshan</body></message>";
Message message = (Message)PacketParserUtils.parseStanza(msgString);

Log.e("message XML->", message.toXML().toString());
Log.e("message getFrom()->", message.getFrom() + ":"); //923442621149:
Log.e("message getStanzaId()->", message.getStanzaId() + ":"); //123:
```

Comment: This will not work anymore with Smack 4.3.+ because of the missing namespaces in the `message` tag. It's better to parse the XML yourself. Refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser